# 2002 Honda civic ex water coming out back of motor

Tags: honda, overheating

I have a 2002 Honda civic VTEC 1.7 motor. I replaced pretty much the whole top end of the motor the heads, all gaskets and everything about your and a half ago and recently the car started overheating again the thermostats been changed. It is the OEM thermostat.
When I put water in radiator it comes out the back of the motor driver side about arms length or so from underneath up on the motor I feel like a hole or something there and that’s where the water is coming out of. Is this the water pump or is it another issue

Answer (score 0):

The seal in the water pump is blown and it's coming out of the weep hole near the alternator and running down. There isn't much else on that side that contains coolant. If you can raise the car and get underneath to look up at it you can see things a lot better.